# How to get JSON response from database with PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, json, api, laravel-5

I am creating a sign-up and sign-in API in JSON form in Laravel. I post the data into database and database receives the data which I sent. But I want the database to send the response in JSON form and I also to want select a file in Postman and select the image, so how do I save image's URL in a directory?

This is my code so far...

**UserController.php**:

```
public function signup(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [

        ]);

        $user = new User([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'user_name' => $request->input('user_name'),
            'profile_discription' => $request->input('profile_discription'),
            'profile_pic' => $request->input('profile_pic'),
            'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number'),
            'location' => $request->input('location')

            ]);

        $user->save();
        return response()->json(['Message' => 'Successfully Created User!'], 201);
```

**web.php**:

```
Route::post('/user/signup', ['uses' => 'UserController@signup']);
```

Comment: Simply `return ['Message' => 'Successfully Created User!']` at the end of your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some function to store your file/image to some path, then store the path to the database.

```
<?php
// Folder in public/upload/
$destinationPath = "upload/";

if ($request->hasFile('profile_pic') && $request->file('profile_pic')->isValid()) {

    // store file to local
    $file = $request->file('profile_pic');
    $ext = $file->guessExtension();
    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    // Move file to your path
    $result = $request->file('profile_pic')->move($destinationPath, $now . $name);
    $finalPath = $destinationPath . '/' . $now . $name;

    /*
    * Save to database code continue here ...
    */
}
```

Or just simply convert the image to BASE64

```
$data = $request->file('profile_pic');
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

 /*
 * Save to database code continue here ...
 */
```

Comment: in UserController i need to use some function like this.

Comment: Thanks very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Response Class first,

```
use Response;
public function signup(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [


    ]);

    $user = new User([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
        'user_name' => $request->input('user_name'),
        'profile_discription' => $request->input('profile_discription'),
        'profile_pic' => $request->input('profile_pic'),
        'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number'),
        'location' => $request->input('location')

        ]);

    $user->save();
$response = array('message'=>'Successfully Created User!');
return Response::json($response);
```

I hope it helps,